# Complex Java Object to Json

Tags: java, json, gson, jackson2

I have a java class like :

```
public class Sclass {
    private Student student;
    private Teacher teacher;

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }
    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }
}

public class Teacher {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
    } 
}

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I want to use `Sclass` in a rest service and thus want a json for the same, please assist.

Comment: Your REST framework, whatever it is, will probably turn that into JSON automatically. Read its documentation. If you're stuck, come back with a concrete, answerable question. "Please assist" is not one.

Comment: I want to test the api, using post man, for which I need to pass the json, thus need some support on that

Comment: Again, Stackoverflow is not a support group. You ask a concrete question, and we try to answer it. That's the principle.

Comment: I am not able to formulate the json object, for this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using `gson`:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setName("Student 1");
student.setAge(18);

Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
teacher.setName("Teacher 1");

Sclass sclass = new Sclass();
sclass.setStudent(student);
sclass.setTeacher(teacher);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(sclass);

System.out.println(json);
```

Output:

```
{"student":{"name":"Student 1","age":18},"teacher":{"name":"Teacher 1"}}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I was using an upper case for "student", it worked